# How can I correctly add the alpha channel to an image extracted from a PDF using PyMuPDF

Tags: python-3.x, png, pymupdf

I am trying to extract images from a PDF using PyMuPDF and [this recipe](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/#how-to-handle-stencil-masks). For some images with a hard edge transparency it works. But for images with a matte transparency, I get artifacts along the edges.

When I extract the image without alpha information and the alpha mask as separate PNGs and combine them using GIMP, the result is as expected, so the information seems to be there.

Can anyone help? Am I missing a step?

```
import fitz

doc = fitz.open(r"Some.pdf")

for i in range(len(doc)):
    for img in doc.getPageImageList(i):
        xref = img[0]
        smask = img[1]
        pix1 = fitz.Pixmap(doc, xref)
        if smask != 0:
            pix2 = fitz.Pixmap(doc, smask)
            pix = fitz.Pixmap(pix1)
            pix.setAlpha(pix2.samples)
        else:
            pix = pix1

        if pix.n - pix.alpha < 4:       # this is GRAY or RGB
            pix.writePNG("img-%s-%s.png" % (i, xref))
        else:               # CMYK: convert to RGB first
            pix1 = fitz.Pixmap(fitz.csRGB, pix)
            pix1.writePNG("img-%s-%s.png" % (i, xref))
            pix1 = None
        pix = None
```

Comment: FYI: I managed to get what I want by saving the opacity mask and the image separately and then combining the images using the PyPng library. The code is pretty ugly and should only be used for small images (because it currently reads the entire images instead of using iterators) so I won't post it right away, but if I get around cleaning it up, I'll share it here.

I would still be interested in an solution using only PyMuPDF, though.